# Print Reports to PDF in Access 2013 but use a looping filter

Tags: ms-access, vba

I need to print the same report over and over again but with a different name for each report.My reports are printing blank. Not certain how to get code to loop through names in a table and to use those names as a filter for the report. See Code below. Seems to be and issue with rec2.

```
Option Compare Database
Option Explicit

Sub PrintSingleRepPerPgDailyReportToPDF()
On Error GoTo PrintToPDF_Err
Dim dadb As DAO.Database
Dim rec1 As DAO.Recordset
Dim rec2 As DAO.Recordset
Dim MyFilter As String
Dim MyPath As String

Dim MyFilename As String
Set dadb = CurrentDb
Set rec1 = dadb.OpenRecordset("tblSalesPPL", dbOpenTable)
Do While rec1.EOF = False
    Set rec2 = dadb.OpenRecordset("Select [Rep Name] from tblSalesPPL")

    MyFilter = "(((tblSales2.Rep)='rec2'))"
    MyPath = "C:\Users\Tallahassee Client\Documents\Reports\Reports Daily\" & "AB_"
    MyFilename = Month(Now) & "." & Day(Now) & "." & Year(Now) & ".pdf"

    DoCmd.OpenReport "rptSales3_SingleRepPerPg_DailyReport_2", acViewPreview, "qrySales3", MyFilter
    DoCmd.OutputTo acOutputReport, "", acFormatPDF, MyPath & MyFilename, True
    DoCmd.Close acReport, "rptSales3_SingleRepPerPg_DailyReport_2"

    PrintToPDF_Exit:
    Exit Sub

    PrintToPDF_Err:
    MsgBox Error$
    Resume PrintToPDF_Exit

    Set rec2 = Nothing
    rec1.MoveNext
Loop

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

If you add `Debug.Print MyFilter` after MyFilter is defined, you will see that you are  filtering the report to match the literal text `rec2`, not to match the value of the variable named rec2. Change your filter line to:

and see if you have better results.

```
Set dadb = CurrentDb
Set rec1 = dadb.OpenRecordset("tblSalesPPL", dbOpenTable)
Do While rec1.EOF = False

    MyFilter = "Rep='" & Replace(rec1![Rep Name], "'", "''") & "'"
    MyPath = "C:\Users\Tallahassee Client\Documents\Reports\Reports Daily\" & "AB_"
    MyFilename = Month(Now) & "-" & Day(Now) & "-" & Year(Now) & ".pdf"

    DoCmd.OpenReport "rptSales3_SingleRepPerPg_DailyReport_2", acViewPreview, "qrySales3", MyFilter
    DoCmd.OutputTo acOutputReport, "", acFormatPDF, MyPath & MyFilename, True
    DoCmd.Close acReport, "rptSales3_SingleRepPerPg_DailyReport_2"

    rec1.MoveNext
Loop

Set rec1 = Nothing
```

so that you have a single loop that calls OpenReport once for every record in tblSalesPPL, using the current value of [Rep Name] as the filter for the report's Rep field.

Comment: :( Not working still.  Access is odd about double quotes in vba. I get and a compile error when I add the quotes the way you did it: Expected: end of statement                                                    MyFilter = "(((tblSales2.Rep)='""&rec2&""'))"
Debug.Print MyFilter

Comment: :( Not working still. Access VBA is odd about quotes.If do the suggested quotes I get a compile error as follows **Expected: end of statement** <br/> MyFilter = "(((tblSales2.Rep)='""&rec2&""'))"
Debug.Print MyFilter

Comment: Can you try pasting the editted code now? You need to preserve the spaces around the & signs.

Comment: So I copied the code you wrote and put it in...now I have a **Compile error: Method or Data Member Not Found**

Comment: When I get the error in vba module it highlights **.[Rep Name]**

Comment: Change the dot in `rec2.[Rep Name]` to and exclamation point `rec2![Rep Name]`   I'm not used to having spaces in field names and dealing with brackets! rec1 and rec2 do nearly the same thing. I think you should drop rec2 altogether and just use rec1.

Comment: I use to not put spaces in field names...not certain when I started that bad habit. So I took rec2 out and replaced with rec1 and made the change above rec1![Rep Name]. So the report prints but its not going through the loop it only prints the first name in my table tblSalesPPL. So I only end up with one report and not one for every person!

Comment: mmkay. So when I made changes above I didn't move **DoWhile rec1.EOF=False** above **Set rec1=dadb.OpenRecordset("Select [Rep Name] from tblSalesPPL")** Now that I've made that change I get an error as follows: **Object variable or with block variable not set**

Comment: Can you join me in chat - I made a room with your username

Comment: I don't think it will let me chat in chat room. says I need a reputation of 20?

Comment: I couldn't get vba to print report without the qrySales3 being involved.

Comment: Yes, it prints a report when I do **DoCmd.OpenReport "rptSales3_SingleRepPerPg_DailyReport_2", acViewPreview, , "Rep='JOHN SMITH'"**

Comment: So it only printed one report for one name. It's telling me the output to action was canceled. Run time error 2501. Each time I run module however it prints one report for a different name each time its run. and then gives above error. Do you think its because **MyPath** doesn't change. The **AB_** part. So each file is saving to the same place with the same name.

Comment: The following line gives error --> **DoCmd.OutputTo acOutputReport, "", acFormatPDF, MyPath & MyFilename, True""

Comment: ok maybe I spoke to soon. It is working but one of the reps names has a **'** in it **O'Neal**. So That created an error with same line. I made the hyphen change. Now the runtime error is 3075 **syntax error (missing operator) in query expression 'Rep='Chris O'Neal"** Not certain why its leaving out the ** ' ** after O'neal

Comment: So it's telling me there's a **compile error unexpected )** but then it highlights the **,** after [Rep Name],

Comment: Please open a new question about dealing with apostrophes and quotes in Access.